# Fill in the letter cycles

Tags: pattern, grid-deduction, letter-sequence

[image: Three overlapping heptagons]

**ITM . NDR . EAU . ULT . TEN . TDP . YMH . RYI . SHM . PED . ODP . HIT . AKL . NPT . UKT . UTS . ESA . PRT . DOR . YMT**

Fill each of the empty circles above with a unique letter. Each of the three letter groups represents the order you would encounter these letters going around *one* of the heptagons clockwise. For example, ITM means going clockwise around one of the heptagons, after you hit **I**, you will hit **T** before you hit **M**. Once all of the letters are filled, the dotted spiral will spell out one final word. What is that word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final word is

> REST

The picture:

> [image]

My strategy:

> First identify which letters are in the heptagon containing M.
>
>  Then identitfy which ones are in the three common circles with other heptagons.
>
>  After that, one can determine the four circles in that heptagon using the clues.
>
>  Then use the same strategy to separate other letters into the remaining two heptagons, find which ones are in the common circles, finally use the clues to fill each one.
>
>
>  Quite straightforward, but nice puzzle!

Comment: Wow. That was way faster than I expected. Good job. :)